# Specify facet fields in solr admin

Tags: solr

Im trying to write a facet query in Solr admin...Given below is the actual query that runs fine...

```
http://localhost:5953/solr/collection1/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=category&facet.field=id
```

In the SOLR admin, when I given the following syntax in facet.fields - ["category","id"]

I get the following error,

```
 "error": {
    "msg": "undefined field: \"[\"category\",\"id\"]\"",
    "code": 400
  }
```

How do I specify the fields in solr admin.

Answer (score 4):

The facet.field input box only allows specifying one field. Solr is interpreting the entire string you put in it as the name of a field--literally `["category","id"]`. You can add more facet.field parameters in the "Raw Query Parameters" box.